# How Do I Connect My Check Box To Button In Pyqt4?

Tags: python-2.7, button, checkbox, pyqt4

I'm building an application in which a check box is connected to a button and the button only gets activated when the check box is marked. I have the button and check box defined in initUI function and i have created a button hide function which ive connected to my check box, but i keep getting an error that 'qbtn'(my button) is not defined. What should i do?

initUI:

```
def initUI(self):   

     # Add push button       
    qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
    #connect to button press
    qbtn.clicked.connect(self.ButtonPress)
    qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())

    qbtn.move(50, 50)
    #Add Check Box
    cb = QtGui.QCheckBox('Agree', self)
    cb.move(20, 20)
    cb.toggle()
    cb.stateChanged.connect(self.ButtonHide)
```

ButtonHide:

```
def ButtonHide(self, state):

        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            qbtn.setEnabled(True) 
        else:
            qbtn.setEnabled(False)
```

Error Message:

```
File "<wingdb_compile>", line 46, in ButtonHide
NameError: global name 'qbtn' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should store references to the UI elements in the parent container,

```
self.qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
...
self.cb = QtGui.QCheckBox('Agree', self)
```

and then in `ButtonHide` refer to `self.qbtn`.